# Simple key-based auth from webservice to Salesforce?

Tags: salesforce

We have an existing app completely outside of Salesforce. Now we'd like to automatically generate leads for them from our separate app. In other words, we have an app that our customers purchase, and we want that app to tell Salesforce when we have a new Lead so that our sales team can follow up with them.

I was expecting this to be a simple rest call, but all of the documentation about authenticating refer to either oauth or using a salesforce user's username & password.

Is there a way to authorize our existing webserver to salesforce so that it can create new Leads without using a username & password?

Alternatively, is there a way to create a username and password that will only be used by our app and not an actual human? I'd like to avoid paying for an extra license.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Salesforce REST API calls need to be made in the context of a Salesforce user.  So you will need an *integration user* that has its own username & password.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is create leads, then check out the [web2lead](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=setting_up_web-to-lead.htm&language=en) feature, an un-authenticated HTTP Post can create a lead in the org.

Comment: Thanks for this - I think we probably will use this actually, since the `integration user` solution (which I can't really believe) will be too expensive